# Laravel Request::create not working with Request::input from CLI

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to call a method from CLI which uses the Request::input so I had to manually create the Request object and the below code is not working in my case. can you please advice.

```
$request = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::create('script/run', 'POST');
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::dispatch($request);
$request->request->add(['adjustment' => '10']);
```

I am trying to call the value from another class

```
dd(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::input('adjustment'));
```

output shows as null but it supposed to show the value 10

I also tried the below option and it did not work as well

```
$request = app('request');
$request->request->add(['adjustment' => '10']);
dd($request->all());
```

returns empty array. If I am able to add input here, it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but when you create the request you are assigning it to a variable, however, when you go to die and dump the value of 'adjustment' you're calling a new request which doesn't have the value of 'adjustment'

To obtain this simply call it from the request you've assigned to `$request`.

```
dd($request->input('adjustment'));
```

Comment: oh!, I am actually calling the value from another class, sorry for not explaining that. is it possible to pass the newly created request and attach it to the main request?

Comment: It would help two know why you're creating two request classes. If you're creating two classes you'd need to pass input to both of them, surely? - or are you expecting the input back from the Route::dispatch() method? if so you'd need to assign that to a variable.

Comment: since I am calling this method from the command line, a default request object does not seem to have created, I tried to use $request = app('request');, but I am unable to add input to that request. So I had to create a new request object. so I assume there is only one request ?

Comment: Simon R thanks! now I added the input to the main request and able to get the values as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer finally, I had to use merge instead of add. below code worked for me.

```
$request = app('request');
$request->merge(['adjustment' => '10']);
dd(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all());
```